# When I change my navbar position to fixed, it changes sides of the screen and shinks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

To begin I'd like to state that I'm using the bootstrap framework and I'm aware they have a navbar template but it doesn't fit what I'm trying to do with this one navigation bar
The bar is supposed to be full width and with a right float which it is until i add position:fixed to it. Then it shrinks down to about 30% screen width and floats to the left.

I added the code snippet from the navibation bar below but I cannot add the bootstrap library to the snipet so it won't look right on here either way.

If you would like to see it live: http://test.suburbandogma.com/test-three.html

```css
.container {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#top-nav {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 padding-top: 0.3em;
 border-bottom: 0.1em solid #ccc;
}

.border-right {
 border-right: 0.1em solid #ccc;
}

#top-list li {
 padding-right: 0.5em;
}

#top-list li:nth-child(6) {
 margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#top-list li a {
 font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #808080;
}

.top-icons {
 position: relative;
 top: 0.2em;
 height: 15px;
 width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="top-nav">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="pull-right list-inline" id="top-list">
     <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Support@domainname.com</a></li>
     <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
     <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive top-icons" src="/images/icons/twitter-icon.svg" alt="Twitter Icon"/>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive top-icons" src="/images/icons/facebook-icon.svg" alt="Facebook Icon"/>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive top-icons" src="/images/icons/skype-icon.svg" alt="Skype Icon"/>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give #top-nav a width of 100% you can also ditch the row and column divs.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top-nav">
    <ul class="pull-right list-inline" id="top-list">
        <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive top-icons" src="/images/icons/twitter-icon.svg" alt="Twitter Icon"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive top-icons" src="/images/icons/facebook-icon.svg" alt="Facebook Icon"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive top-icons" src="/images/icons/skype-icon.svg" alt="Skype Icon"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#top-nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got so caught up in bootstrap I didn't realize the solution was so simple

Answer (score 1):

Add: 
    width:100%;
to your css for #top-nav

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the .row (that's for the grid system or a similar pattern) or the .col-md-12 (which is extra unnecessary html) or the .container (it has a width at different breakpoints and is required for the grid).

A fixed position needs a width or a position. Also, you didn't close your links or your list on the icons.

### https://jsbin.com/putajo/1/

https://jsbin.com/putajo/1/edit?html,css,output

HTML

```
<div id="top-nav">
        <ul class="pull-right list-inline" id="top-list">
            <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Support@domainname.com</a></li>
            <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
            <li class="border-right"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#top-nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #ccc;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.border-right {
    border-right: 0.1em solid #ccc;
}

#top-list li {
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

#top-list li:nth-child(6) {
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#top-list li a {
    font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #808080;
}

.top-icons {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.2em;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```